# Evaluate polynominal function

Tags: r, polynomials

Im trying to evaluate this polynomial: 
[image]

Using two different approaches, one is directly and the other is horner´s rule. My code:

Direct way:

```
directpoly1 <- function(x, coef, seqcoef = seq(coef) - 1) {
  sum(coef*x^seqcoef)
}
directpoly <- function(x, coef) {
  seqcoef <- seq(coef) - 1
  sapply(x, directpoly1, coef, seqcoef)
```

Horner´s rule:

```
hornerpoly <- function(x, coef) {
  n <- length(coef);
  a <- rep(0, n);
  a[n] <- coef[n];
  while (n > 0) {
    n <- n - 1;
    a[n] <- coef[n] + a[n + 1] * x;
  }
  return(a[1]);
}
```

I need to compare the speed of the two different approaches, but I can´t figure out how to do that. My initial approach is:

```
system.time(directpoly(x=seq(-10,10, length=5000000), c(1:39)))
system.time(hornerpoly(x=seq(-10,10, length=5000000), c(1:39)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you check the running time directly at the terminal?

Comment: What do you not like about your approach?

Comment: @Roman when using either approach I need to type in my coefficients which runs from 39 to 1, but the particular function i need to evaluate is 2x^n-x^n-1 + ... , and i dont think Im doing it correctly, as im now just typing in values for the coefficients.

Comment: Try using the `microbenchmark` package in R. Very useful for testing the speed of different methods: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/microbenchmark.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
ptm <- proc.time()
#.... your function ...
proc.time() - ptm
```

Do this for second function as well and compare the times.

Comment: This is exactly what `system.time()` is doing.